# Title missed in MongoDB Group BY

Tags: mongodb, project, aggregation

I have the problem that mongoDB does not print the title in combination with aggregation and grouping. 
I got only the following output: `{ "_id" : null, "max":3428}.`

But I want the output in this form: `{"_id":null, "max":3428, "title":MovieTItle}`.

I tried something like title:`"$title", title:$push: "$title".`
But nothing of this works. I have attached the code.
I hope you could help me, thanks :)

```
db.movieDBLens.aggregate([
     {$project : 
          {_id : "", count:{$sum:{$size: "$ratings.rating"}}}},
     {$group: {_id: null, max: { $max: "$count" }}}
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add "title" in the $project stage as below:

```
db.movieDBLens.aggregate([
     {$project : 
          {"_id"   : "", 
           "count" : {$sum:{$size: "$ratings.rating"}},
           "title" : 1
          }
     },
     {$group: {_id: null, max: { $max: "$count" }}}
]);
```